# IntelliJ: How can I "kick" the error highlighting process to get it unstuck?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm working on a `create-react-app` codebase with Typescript enabled.

I find that IDEA real-time syntax analysis of my code often gets "stuck".
I make a mistake, IDEA shows the little red squiggles almost immediately, then I fix the errors but sometimes the red squiggles don't always go away.

For example:
[image: screenshot of error highlighting]

There's nothing wrong with the above code any more, but IDEA still shows the red squiggles, both in the code and the project tool window / changelist window.

I've found that I can "un-stick" the code analysis by killing any/all the `node.exe` sub-process that IDEA has.  Presumably one of those sub-process is "stuck" and when I kill the process, IDEA launches a new one and the syntax error highlighting will disappear.

Obviously, I'd prefer that the code analysis not get stuck at all, but failing that is there a way I can "un-stick" the code analysis from within the IDE?

I'm looking for something faster than re-starting IDEA (or clearing caches, etc.)

Using IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 (Ultimate edition) on Windows.

`package.json` configuration and the rest of the code can be found here: https://github.com/kopi-cloud/cabbage/tree/main/app

Comment: what errors can you see namely when you hover over the highlighted lines? Does restarting typescript language service (can be done by clicking the Typescript widget in the IDE status bar) fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment from Lena, restarting the Typescript language service will fix issues with stale highlighting errors.

The Typescript status bar widget is usually found at the bottom right of the editor:
[image]

Tested with IDEA 2021.1.2